# How to deal with sharp door latch corners?

Tags: doors, latches

There is a doorway that sometimes people walk through and get scratched on their arms by the latch on the door and occasionally it even draws blood. I think it's because the two external corners of the door latch are too sharp.

How can I make the door latch safer? Is it OK to use a Dremel rotary tool to round out or flatten the corners a bit?

Comment: A picture of the latch would help us in offering solutions

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dremel may be able to work but it is also possible to way overdo the grinding that a high speed tool like this can do.

If all you want to do is to break sharp corners all you need is a low cost hand file. File with a cutting surface called a mill file will give you nice smooth cuts of the sharp edges.

Here is a typical mill cut file.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/80755333)*</sup>

Comment: A 4” inch angle grinder would take off too much material too quckly but a dremel will be fine with a sanding paper.

Comment: You can just use the grinder wheel like a file and it'll work. They just need to make it "not sharp", which should be 3-4 strokes at most.

Comment: I agree a mill file is the proper tool for the job a bastard file would be two aggressive and would not leave as smooth of an edge.

Comment: or even a sharpening stone. or the back of utility knife